# Combining two PDFs files side-by-side

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have two PDF files, each one containing a vectorial figure. How can I combine them into a single PDF so that the two figures are placed side-by-side?

---

Example with file [01.pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4y6Mj_UZoTEaFhzOGk4WnZjcHc) and [file02.pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4y6Mj_UZoTEYW1WWjZObk52M2c):

[image][image]

desired output (approximately), which should be vectorial:

[image]

I am fine using Microsoft Windows or Mac OS X. I tried to do it using Adobe Acrobate Pro but it didn't seem straightforward.

Comment: please have a look at this https://forums.adobe.com/thread/711593

Comment: do you want to just merge only these two pdf , i can do it for you on photoshop